# Xpages Extension Library Name Picker Not working

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am not able to get the name picker in latest version of extension library to work. Here is my Xpage code. I have tried every name picker type available.

**I deployed my code to another server and I get this error message: Syntax Error: Unexpected token "<"**

No error on firebug or server console.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:inputTextarea id="streamApprovers" value="" multipleSeparator=";" multipleTrim="true"></xp:inputTextarea>
    <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="streamApprovers" dialogTitle="Select approver(s)" listHeight="auto" listWidth="auto">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false" nameList="peopleByLastName" addressBookDb="names.nsf">
            </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
    </xe:namePicker>
</xp:view>
```

[image: Please have a look at the screenshot. Highlighted area shows JSON in Firebug console.]

Comment: Try replacing inputTextArea with inputText.

Comment: Tried that ..same issue. It does not show any names...search does not return anything...so seems to be some configuration issue but I have manager rights everywhere!!

Comment: Can you confirm you're demo XPage is on server not local NSF please

Comment: There was a similar question posted recently I think. The solution was that the user was not logged in and therefore had no access to names.nsf. May be a different issue here though

Comment: Thanks guys.. my XPage is on server and I am logged in. I have attached a screenshot showing picker and JSON response.

Comment: I think we need some more information, because I've tried your code on my machine and it works without any problems. 
Do you use any theme?
What browser and what version are you trying with ?

Comment: Hi Frederik, I have created a custom theme extending Bootstrap theme. I am using FF 40 for my testing but it is not working in latest chrome as well as IE 11. If it helps, I have value pickers which are working just fine. Also I created a new testing database (without any theme ) and result is same.

Comment: One more thing, it is working as XPinC!!

Comment: Guys one more question, I am using updatesite to deploy the extlib (and other osgi plugins). Which id should I use to sign these with? Also I tried a value picker on Names.nsf. It is not loading either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for wasting your valuable time. Name picker is working fine. My admin has **removed web access to names.nsf by setting "Maximum internet name and password" to NO Access**. Posting it here as it may help some wandering soul.